# Is this an equivalence relation and explaination?

Tags: equivalence-relations

The question is:

> Let $A = \{\text{cat, dog, mouse, bird}\}$ and let $R$ be the binary relation
>   on $A$ given by $R = \{(x,y) \mid \text{$x$ and $y$ have no letter in common}\}$.
>
> (a) Draw $R$.
>   (b) State whether or not $R$ is an equivalence relation, explaining your
>   answer.

I have done both parts of the question, and wanted to confirm if the answers and my reasoning behind the answers are correct, and would be acceptable for an exam answer.

(a)

[image]

(b)

No, it is not an equivalence relation, as the relation is not reflexive. An example contradiction would be $R(\text{dog, dog})$, which is not reflexive, because they have letters in common.

Comment: I find it perfect.

Comment: Basically correct. I would reword to say “$R(dog,dog)$, which is not **true**, because *dog* and *dog* have (all three) letters in common.”

Comment: @SteveKass I find irrelevant that all letters are common. A single common letter prevents the relationship.

Comment: Yes, of course. I think the parenthetical comment could be enlightening to a reader learning the material for the first time. If the aim of the proof is to convince a more seasoned audience, it could be left out. That's my opinion as a teacher, however.

Comment: One may note that it also cannot be repaired simply by extending $R$ to include all pairs $(x,x)$, either, as $R$ is also not transitive: $R(\text{mouse}, \text{cat})$ and $R(\text{cat}, \text{dog})$, but it is not true that $R(\text{mouse}, \text{dog})$. However, this is extra, simply noting it isn't reflexive is enough.